# Consume Kafka messages from a different container in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

Below is my docker-compose file:

```
   version: "3"
    services:
      app:
        image: app
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "8001:8081"
        depends_on:
          - kafka
          - zookeeper
          - consumer
        environment:
          - KAFKA_HOST = kafka

  zookeeper:
    image: "wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest"
    ports:
        - "2181:2181"
    hostname: zookeeper   

  kafka:
    image: "wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.2.0"
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    hostname: kafka
    links: 
     - zookeeper:zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "Topic01:2:2" #TOPIC:PARTITON:REPLICATION
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS: "60000"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://:9092'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092'

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  consumer:
    image: consumer:latest
    build:
      context: ./consumer
    ports:
      - "8283:8283"
```

Text stream is generated using container for `app` image and is able to produce the messages.

It is verified by navigating inside the kafka container:

`docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID of Kafka Image> /bin/bash`

when I manually run the below script inside the container

`kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic Topic01 --from-beginning`

I can see the chunk of text that is being produced.

But when I try to read the same data from the container of the image `consumer`, It gives me blank,

Method tried:

`docker exec` inside the consumer container, and ran the below python code:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('Topic01', bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092')
for messages in consumer:
        print(messages)
```

It prints nothing.

Is it because my docker-compose file is wrong or the mistake in the python code?

Comment: how many partitions does that topic have?

Comment: @aran I have given 2 partitions, in the compose file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Kafka documentation for listeners:

> Listener List - Comma-separated list of URIs we will listen on and the listener names. If the listener name is not a security protocol, listener.security.protocol.map must also be set. Specify hostname as 0.0.0.0 to bind to all interfaces. **Leave hostname empty to bind to default interface**. Examples of legal listener lists: PLAINTEXT://myhost:9092,SSL://:9091 CLIENT://0.0.0.0:9092,REPLICATION://localhost:9093

You are setting `KAFKA_LISTENERS` to `PLAINTEXT://:9092`, so it binds to default interface, which might not be accessible from the outside of your Kafka container (while at the same time it works fine with console consumer using localhost). Give it a try and specify `KAFKA_LISTENERS` as `PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`, to check if you consumer starts to consume messages.

Comment: should I be using the same value in the code as well? i.e; the ‘bootstrap_server’ argument.